# Finding All possible combination of the words given in a word

Tags: loops, recursion, combinations, permutation

I was writing a program to generate the all possible words(can be meaningless) with the help of letters present in word entered by user.Everything is working correctly but it is giving some repeated word in output.
Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Combination {
    int i = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String input =scan.nextLine();
        char arr[] = input.toCharArray();
        int length = arr.length;
        

        Combination call = new Combination();
        int total=call.factorial(length);

        call.getCombinations(arr, length,total);
        scan.close();
    }

    void getCombinations(char arr[], int l,int noOfCombination) {
        if (i > noOfCombination - 1) {
            return;
        }
        i++;
        if (l - 2 < 0) {
            char temp = arr[l - 1];
            arr[l - 1] = arr[0];
            arr[0] = temp;
            System.out.println(new String(arr));

            getCombinations(arr, arr.length,noOfCombination);
        } else {
            System.out.println(new String(arr));
            char temp = arr[l - 1];
            arr[l - 1] = arr[l - 2];
            arr[l - 2] = temp;

            getCombinations(arr, l - 1,noOfCombination);
        }
    }

    int factorial(int n)
    {
        if(n==1){
            return 1;
        }
        return n*factorial(n-1);
    }
}
```

I was expecting that the program will not give repeated words but some words of output were repeated.I tried ChatGPT to solve the problem but chatGPT also failed to find mistake and correct it.

Comment: javascript is not the same as java.

Comment: Where did you get that algorithm from? Why would it *not* output duplicates?

Comment: Your code swaps only *adjacent* characters. Is that a requirement?

Comment: What's the actual/expected output for a given input?